# Representing nested folders as DisplayObjects

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm working on a world builder that will load a toolkit which is represented by an xml document. The document will look similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toolkit>
    <folder name="environment">
        <folder name="terrain">
            <tool name="grass">
                <classname>game.terrain.Grass</classname>
                <layer>terrain</layer>
            </tool>
            <tool name="dirt">
                <classname>game.terrain.Dirt</classname>
                <layer>terrain</layer>
            </tool>
            <tool name="water">
                <classname>game.terrain.Water</classname>
                <layer>water</layer>
            </tool>
        </folder>
        <folder name="mobile">
            <folder name="enemies">
                <tool name="youngzombie">
                    <classname>game.mobiles.YoungZombie</classname>
                    <layer>mobiles</layer>
                </tool>
                <tool name="zombie">
                    <classname>game.mobiles.Zombie</classname>
                    <layer>mobiles</layer>
                </tool>
            </folder>
        </folder>
        <tool name="player">
            <classname>game.mobiles.Player</classname>
            <layer>mobiles</layer>
        </tool>
</toolkit>
```

Now, I want to be able to represent this structure in flash. Vertical layout is easy enough, simply placing the elements from top to bottom. It gets mind-boggling when I need to do the following:

1. Be able to click any folder and have all its children hidden/shown.
2. Position the elements horizontally based on hierarchical position (indent children of folders, children of the child folders, etc)
3. Position the folders/tools vertically when folders above and in the same "directory" are hidden.

It either sounds a lot easier than it is, or I'm missing a vital and obvious step.

Just to save confusion - when I make reference to "folders" and "tools", these are a MovieClip which is a simple block with text over it, like:

```
------
folder
------
    ------
    folder
    ------
        ----
        tool
        ----
        ----
        tool
        ----
    ------
    folder
    ------
        ----
        tool
        ----
----
tool
----
```

Comment: Hi Marty, you should definitively go Flex and use a Tree!

Comment: @Kodiak Thanks :), would you be able to provide a resource that would explain what a Tree is and how I would go about implementing it?

Comment: He's referring to a tree list view. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_8.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing the same without using tree because the layout isn't usefull for me (mobile app).
You can make a for each that reads every element in your xml and add to every tag a parent and the element his children.
I make a view with a tileList and I give an arraylist as dataprovider-tag that is filled with the elements of the xmlfile. The list will be changed by clicking on an item or previous button. You can make a onDataChange in your tileList itemrenderer that recreates the tileList by the new data in your arraylist
If you click on an item you can show the children.
If you click previous folder you can show the parent object (that has his own children).

Don't know if you understand the way of working. If you have some questions about it, just ask ;).